# generar array con información de un txt java

Tags: java, spring-boot, txt, array-bidimensional

debo llenar un Array con una información de un archivo txt, la idea es que se vaya generando el array cada vez que empieze una linea con "C", actualmente ya genero los arrays pero lo esta generando por cada linea, cada linea del archivo es un array

se esta generando asi

```
Array listo: [C375, ZVMY24102022E018, 1F02375, 830130106, 00.00, 000053465.00000008536.00]
Array listo: [D, 1, 7702860114202, E01800000000010.000, 000000005346.50000000000000.00]
Array listo: [C334, ZVMY24102022E018, 1F02334, 900045858, 00.00, 000080890.00000012915.00]
Array listo: [D, 1, 7703455531107, E01800000000001.000, 000000030990.00000000000000.00]
Array listo: [D, 2, 7703455543131, E01800000000001.000, 000000049900.00000000000000.00]
Array listo: [C376, ZVMY24102022E018, 1F02376, 830130106, 00.00, 000053465.00000008536.00]
Array listo: [D, 1, 7702860114202, E01800000000010.000, 000000005346.50000000000000.00]
```

lo estoy generando con este codigo

```
public void Procesar() {
    File folder = new File("E:\\\\reportescve\\\\input");
    System.out.println("leyendo archivos");
    String[] files = folder.list();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Directorio Vacio");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directorio con archivos");
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(file.toString());
                String filepathname = file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase();
                if (filepathname.endsWith(".flag")) {
                    System.out.println("flag");
                    try {
                        delete(file);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (filepathname.endsWith(".txt")) {
                        System.out.println("Leyendo Interfaz " + file.getName());
                        String nombreArchivo = file.toString();
                        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();
                        FileReader fr = null;
                        BufferedReader br;

                        try {
                            fr = new FileReader(nombreArchivo);
                            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                            // Lectura del fichero
                            String linea;
                            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                lista.add(linea);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                if (fr != null) {
                                    fr.close();
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                e2.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            }
                        }
                        String[] str = new String[lista.size()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                            str[i] = lista.get(i);
                        }
                        for (String k : str) {
                            String y = k.replaceAll(" +", " ");
                            String[] words = y.split(" ");
                            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
                            //words = pattern.split(y);
                            System.out.println("Array listo: " + Arrays.toString(words));

                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Archivo Testigo");
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // findAllFilesInFolder(file);
                System.out.println("else " + file.isDirectory());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

necesito que quede de esta forma

```
[C375, ZVMY24102022E018, 1F02375, 830130106, 00.00, 000053465.00000008536.00],[D, 1, 7702860114202, E01800000000010.000, 000000005346.50000000000000.00]

[C334, ZVMY24102022E018, 1F02334, 900045858, 00.00, 000080890.00000012915.00],[D, 1, 7703455531107, E01800000000001.000, 000000030990.00000000000000.00],[D, 2, 7703455543131, E01800000000001.000, 000000049900.00000000000000.00]
```

la idea es generar un array multidimensional que almacenen las C en la primera posición de la dimension del Array y las d en las siguientes, necesito esto para poder generar otro archivo y unos registros en la BD con los datos organizados de esa forma.

alguien de la comunidad tiene algun ejemplo para poder generar ese array multidimensional en java Spring Boot ?

Comment: Una recomendación... si quieres que tu código sea más fácil de leer y tenga menos anidamientos, puedes poner todas tus comprobaciones al inicio del método y te evitas todos tus `else`. Por ejemplo `if (files.length == 0) { System.out.println("Directorio Vacio"); return; }`, a continuación pondrías el segundo if... luego el tercero... así todos los que necesites, si entra a cualquiera de ellos el `return` asegura que no continúe la ejecución del código de abajo, de esa manera el código queda más "plano" y fácil de leer, especialmente cuando tenemos que seguir el flujo mentalmente!

Comment: ¿No bastaría con reemplazar `]\n[D` por `],[D`?

Comment: @Benito-B muchas gracias por tu comentario, voy a implementar las mejoras, pero queria saber si depronto tienes algun consejo para abordar el problema que plantee en la pregunta para poder solucionar el caso

Comment: @Sal me podrias indicar como realizo ese procedimiento en Java, es que el Array se genera es por cada linea del archivo pero asi no lo necesito pero no encuentro una forma de realizarlo